# After installing Ubuntu 13.10 I get this message "the disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present"

Tags: boot, swap

I've just finished installing Ubuntu 13.10 on my computer.

When I start the computer, after the Ubuntu logo fades away, I see this message:

> the disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present

Then the login screen appears and when I enter my password I go to my desktop.

Is this normal? Do I need to do something about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes up when your swap partition cannot be mounted for some reason.

To solve the error:

Turns off swap:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

comment existing swap configuration in /etc/crypttab

```
cryptswap1 /dev/sdXX /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

comment existing swap configuration in /etc/fstab

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

re-format swap partition with gparted as linux-swap

```
sudo mkswap /dev/sdXX
```

mark somewhere the UUID value that the previous command returns

Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 4208636 KiB
no label, UUID=06a9be15-d05b-466d-bfe3-a086bb9cdba0
update /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume with the new UUID

Check your new UUID

```
RESUME=UUID=06a9be15-d05b-466d-bfe3-a086bb9cdba0
sudo update-initramfs -u (update initramfs)
sudo swapon /dev/sdXX (enable swap, XX depends on your setup)
sudo ecryptfs-setup-swap (encrypt swap)
```

[source and more information](http://punygeek.blogspot.com/2012/10/ubuntu-1204-how-to-solve-disk-drive-for.html)